# In Golang, why is conn.Write tcp response empty?

Tags: go, tcp

I have a tcp server that reads a file that sends the file content to the client.

The 'status.txt' file contains only a boolean.

When I curl, this shows `true` (with leading space).

```
dat, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./status.txt")
conn.Write([]byte(" " + string(dat)))
```

Whereas this code results in `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`.

```
conn.Write([]byte(string(dat)))
```

Any clue why this happens? I don't want to have to pad my response string.

Comment: `ioutil.ReadFile` returns the byte slice. So just write as is `conn.Write(dat)` or write without pad `conn.Write([]byte("" + string(dat)))`.

Comment: @jeevatkm I've tried both. I believe the first returns empty. The second returns `%`.

Comment: Why are you using curl if your protocol is not HTTP?. Use Netcat (nc localhost port) and it will be working.

Comment: @RadekZałuska Doh! That did it. Please write the answer and I will accept it. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use Curl if you are not using HTTP protocol. Curl is expecting certain format of the message that is compatible with HTTP protocol.
If you send text "true", that is for sure not valid HTTP Header.

To test TCP server use Netcat instead:

```
nc localhost port
```